# Reading input fields separated by spaces

Tags: bash, shell-script, posix, newlines, read

How can I read in POSIX `bash` input like this:

```
<name>,<tag1> <tag2> <tag3>…
```

I tried 
`while read line;do done` but this wants newlines, all I have is spaces.

(Is **IFS** solution? If yes, how? (I don't fully understand IFS.))

Comment: Are these going to be four fields or two fields ?

Comment: I don't know what do you mean. Who?

Comment: If it wants newlines where you have spaces, `tr`anslate spaces to newlines. (`tr ' ' '\n'`)

Comment: @don_crissti I want to work with each of tags alone

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: `echo '<name>,<tag1> <tag2> <tag3>' | tr ", " "\n"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an array:

```
echo '<name>,<tag1> <tag2> <tag3>' | while IFS=" ," read -a foo; do echo ${foo[@]}; done
```

Output:

```
<name> <tag1> <tag2> <tag3>
```

---

From `man bash`:

IFS: The Internal Field Separator that is used for word splitting after expansion and to split lines into words with the read builtin command.